# Difference between sending particle one by one and sending them together in double-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In quantum mechanics, if I do the double-slit experiment, and I send one electron each time, there will be interference fringes, as Dirac said, each electron interferes with itself. There is no interaction between each electron. If I send a bunch of electrons together, they should obey the rule of "Fermi–Dirac statistics", they are in an entangled state before reaching the slits, so in the above two situations, will the interference fringes be the same?

Comment: " If I send a bunch of electrons together, they should obey the rule of "Fermi–Dirac statistics"," this is not true for incoherent beams in the lab, used in the labs. entanglements  has been observed in special cases https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/01/200116144105.htm

Comment: Indeed, electron beam doesn't imply automatically that electrons in a packet are entangled. Most probably, they are not, because you have to do something for them to entangle.

Comment: how could I make two electrons entangled?